# Create a 2013 Wiki page with Powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, wiki

I have a Sharepoint 2013 instance running on a server. I want to create a script that writes wiki pages from files. So while searching the internet, I found some code for C#, VB, and some PS Code that was not exactly doing what I wanted.

What I have so far:

```
$pageLayout = '<div class="ExternalClassCFBA8CDC81B34264A81647E2260499B4"><table id="layoutsTable" style="width:100%"><tbody><tr style="vertical-align:top"><td colspan="2"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width:100%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"><div class="ExternalClass84D2F659CA274C02B313B2039A7DCEF6">Template Preview</div></div></div></td></tr><tr style="vertical-align:top"><td style="width:49.95%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width:100%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"><div class="ExternalClass84D2F659CA274C02B313B2039A7DCEF6"> </div></div> </div></td><td style="width:49.95%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width:100%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"></div> </div></td></tr></tbody></table><span id="layoutsData" style="display:none">true,false,2</span></div>';
$SPSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://sharepoint");
$OpenWeb = $SpSite.OpenWeb();
$rootFolder = $OpenWeb.Lists['MyWiki'].RootFolder;
$files = $rootFolder.Files;
$newPage = $files.Add($rootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Testpage", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::WikiPage);
# Dispose stuff...
```

I already get an exception here:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): ""
At C:\createWiki.ps1:31 char:5
+     $newPage = $files.Add($rootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Testpage", [Micr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException
```

But the parameters seem to be correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this one on $file.add($rootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Testpage.aspx", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::WikiPage)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question. You first part helped me a lot.
I implemented your script with .aspx after the page title. That works fine.

Your example works like this:

```
$pageLayout = '<div class="ExternalClassCFBA8CDC81B34264A81647E2260499B4"><table id="layoutsTable" style="width:100%"><tbody><tr style="vertical-align:top"><td colspan="2"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width:100%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"><div class="ExternalClass84D2F659CA274C02B313B2039A7DCEF6">Template Preview</div></div></div></td></tr><tr style="vertical-align:top"><td style="width:49.95%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width:100%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"><div class="ExternalClass84D2F659CA274C02B313B2039A7DCEF6"> </div></div> </div></td><td style="width:49.95%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width:100%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"></div> </div></td></tr></tbody></table><span id="layoutsData" style="display:none">true,false,2</span></div>';
$SPSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://sharepoint");
$OpenWeb = $SpSite.OpenWeb();
$rootFolder = $OpenWeb.Lists['MyWiki'].RootFolder;
$files = $rootFolder.Files;
$newPage = $files.Add($rootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Testpage.aspx", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::WikiPage);
# Dispose stuff...
```

By the way; You're not using your page layout in this example.